# Dropping brackets / key in bibliography with alphabetic style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

For a CV, I want to print a list of publications without being citing them in the text. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,natbib=true,isbn=false,style=alphabetic,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.bib} 
@inproceedings{rutz2011reproducibility,
    AUTHOR      = {Rutz, Hanns Holger and Miranda, Eduardo and Eckel, Gerhard},
    TITLE       = {{Reproducibility and Random Access in Sound Synthesis}},
    BOOKTITLE   = {Proceedings of the 37th International Computer Music Conference},
    ADDRESS     = {Huddersfield},
    PAGES       = {515--522},
    YEAR        = {2011}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{rutz2011reproducibility}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this places the key in brackets `[RME11]` in front of the entry:

[image]

I can use the `authoryear` style of course, but then the formatting of the names in the references is not how I want. What is the easiest way to stick to the `alphabetic` style but dropping the brackets/key?

I am using biber and biblatex (and I don't want to change that).

Comment: I can't reproduce this - I get a key `[RME11]' instead of empty brackets.

Comment: @AndrewSwann - that's right, I see this now after running biber repeatedly. I will update the question. The problem remains though: I want to get rid of that bracket box altogether.

Comment: Do you have other items you are citing in a regular way?  If not, look on page 126 of the biblatex documentation which discusses defining bibliography environments and the first example is one without labels.

Comment: @AndrewSwann - excellent, that does it!

Comment: I would suggest using the `authortitle` style. You can modify the name format to your liking. `\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{first-last}` (and maybe also for `default`) would be my guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Andrew Swann pointed out, the label (that's what biblatex calls it) can be suppressed by redefining the bibliography environment:

```
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
{\list
{}
{\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
\setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
\setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
{\endlist}
{\item}
```